# Copy from S3 AVRO file to Table in Redshift Results in All Null Values

Tags: copy, amazon-redshift, avro

I am trying to copy an AVRO file that is stored in S3 to a table I created in Redshift and I am getting all null values. However, the AVRO file does not have null values in it. I see the following error when I look at the log: "Missing newline: Unexpected character 0x79 found at location 9415"

I did some research online and the only post I could find said that values would be null if the column name case in the target table did not match the source file. I have ensured the case for the column in the target table is the same as the source file.

Here is mock snippet from the AVRO file:

```
Objavro.schemaƒí{"type":"record","name":"something","fields":[{"name":"g","type":["string","null"]},{"name":"stuff","type":["string","null"]},{"name":"stuff","type":["string","null"]}
```

Here is the sql code I am using in Redshift:

```
create table schema.table_name (g varchar(max)); 
copy  schema.table_name 
from 's3://bucket/folder/file.avro'
iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxx:role/xx-redshift-readonly' 
format as avro 'auto';
```

I am expecting to see a table with one column called g where each row has the value stuff.

Comment: Make sure the values in your AVRO file are types that are accepted by Redshift. Unless you're using Redshift Spectrum, your types are limited to this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_Supported_data_types.html